# Why is Google Maps Not Populating All Zip codes From Google Sheets Using Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm created a map in Google Data Studio using zip codes to fill certain area's within the map. However, only 3 zip codes are filled and the other's are not. I tried importing the zip codes as a CSV and Google Sheets and I'm getting the same results.

I made sure the column is being seen as zip codes. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

[image]

Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GmcfmpX1haVESQWMMN-DxyCeZ3JKhzB6rhB5ubPcp-Y/edit?usp=sharing)):

| zipcode-1 |
| --- |
| 06510 |
| 06511 |
| 06512 |
| 06513 |
| 06515 |
| 06519 |
| 06514 |

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4b8705d0-1a07-4688-a4e7-3e5657b998a3) report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 0) Summary

1. ***Issue***: The [geo type](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9843174), zip code, may exist in multiple countries
2. ***Suggestion***: Create a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) which adds a country value

## 1) Issue

The problem occurs as Google Data Studio would need to "*guess*" what the country is. This is because a zip code, while unique to a specific country may not be unique when considering all countries in the world (this also applies to other geo types such as city).

## 2) Suggestion

Explicitly stating the country would ensure that that values are specific.

This can be achieved using the format:

> Geo Field, Country

The values would look like:

> 06510, United States

A [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) of the **Zip Code** field (titled `zipcode-1`) with a `,`  followed by the **Country** (United States) would display the `Geo` values as expected:

### 2.1) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685)

```
CONCAT(zipcode-1, ", ", "United States")
```

**NOTE**: In this specific case, the country has to be manually stated within `""` as there is no country field, however, if there is a `Country` field, use: `CONCAT(Geo Field, ", ", Country)`

### 2.2) Type

```
Geo > Postal Code
```

The output will look like:

| zipcode-1 | Geo |
| --- | --- |
| 06510 | 06510, United States |
| 06511 | 06511, United States |
| 06512 | 06512, United States |
| 06513 | 06513, United States |
| 06515 | 06515, United States |
| 06519 | 06519, United States |
| 06514 | 06514, United States |

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5d949209-688f-4ca1-92ac-47331d26f530) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZpoLIYliyzz1ETjOAx-w5WeEDDsoS02YY4nvqjFk7s/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]