# Data Studio filled map with country and postal code information

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a filled map on a postal code level with count distinct customers (i.e. fields `Location` = Postal Code and `Color metric` = Customers (Count Distinct)) for European area.

It works perfectly when I select the `Location` = Country (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes), but when I select `Location` = Postal Code, as many countries have similar postal codes, it gets messy. Only some regions in the US are filled, but my actual customers are in Europe.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816071/google-maps-not-populating-all-zip-codes-from-google-sheets-using-google-data-st) and tried to replicate it by creating a new field with Country and Postal Code combined. I have tried many distinct standards:

```
CONCAT(Postal Code, ", ", Country) (Field type: Postal Code)
CONCAT(Postal Code, ", ", TOCOUNTRY(Country)) (Field type: Postal Code)
```

If I change the `Layer Type` to Bubbles (instead of Filled areas), it works a bit better, but I would like to have filled areas (postal code level).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It has worked for me, change the type of map.
I used this.
CONCAT(POSTAL, ", ", TOCOUNTRY(CNS_COUNTRY))